# How do you make the Bootstrap navbar logo and menu have "padding" on the left and right, respectively?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

Right now, the logo and menu are aligned to the far-left and far-right of the screen on my website. I would like them to stay a set percentage distance (as opposed to absolute distance) away from the extremes so that it works well even when you resize the page.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using a `container` within your navbar as described in the [Bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/navbar/#containers)? With a container, the logo and menu button will be on the far left and right for small screens, but within the container size on larger screens.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to have your logo and menu some space from the left & right of the screen, if it is true then you can give padding to the left & right of the navbar itself it will automatically push the logo and menu towards the middle of the screen here is the code you can follow.

```
<nav class="navbar">
  // YOUR CODE GOES HERE
</nav>

.navbar{
  padding: 0 20px //insted of 20px you can give it in X% as well.
}
```

and, If I miss understood the question please let me know.